# How to make the side-bar stick to left in table unless scrolled? (pure CSS)

Tags: css, html, html-table

I am trying to create a table where the header will stick if the user scrolls top-down and the side bar sticks if the user scrolls right-left. In short two of them will be visible at anytime. None of them gets hidden away because of being scrolled

Please check my image

[image: screenshot]

for further explanation.

Check the link: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kpzN/205/)

I intend to accomplish this using css only.

```css
.scrolltable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.scrolltable > .header {} 
.scrolltable > .body {
  /*noinspection CssInvalidPropertyValue*/

  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}
th,
td {
  min-width: 150px;
}

#constrainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 89%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 149px;
  height: 85vh;
}

.scrolltable .header{background:none;}

.left-sticky{
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 17px;
  width: 138px !important;
  max-width: 138px !important;
}

table tr td{text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="table-section-area table-section-area-bottom" id="main-bottom-table">
  <div class="">
    <div id="constrainer">
      <div class="scrolltable">
        <table class="header table-striped unique-table ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th overdata="true" colspan="1"  class="left-sticky">
                <div>(S)</div>
              </th>
              <th>
                first
              </th>
              <th>
                second
              </th>
              <th>
                first
              </th>
              <th>
                second
              </th>
              <th>
                first
              </th>
              <th>
                second
              </th>
              <th>
                first
              </th>
              <th>
                second
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
        <div class="body">
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="left-sticky">leftbar</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
                <td>3434</td>
                <td>1434</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when saying "make the left side-bar stick to the left unless the user scrolls the table" do you actually mean "when" or "while" instead of "unless"? Your sentence put this way means the side-bar should NOT stick when the user scrolls, and I have the feeling it's the contrary that you want...

Comment: Hi, please check my image link I have attached. What I mean Left side-bar moves with respect to top down scroll and top header moves with right-left scroll.

Comment: you might want to update the question as that's not very clear from it...

Comment: I did, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there isn't a workaround for this other than using javascript. Since accomplishing this will require so much nesting of divs and tables that it's almost not worth it whilst being totally an impossible task by me. Thank you, goodbye.